# Using scope function inside directives fails in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have an Angular with a link like this...

```
scope: {
      etud:"="
}

link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
        scope.getWarningClass = function(){
            var alertClass = "";
            if(scope.etud <= 2){
                alertClass = "red_alert";
            }
            else if(scope.etud <= 4){
                alertClass = "yellow_alert";
            }

            return alertClass;
        }
}
```

and a partial like...

```
<div class="sane" ng-class="getWarningClass()"></div>
```

I am trying to test this using jasmine like...

```
          beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, $rootScope) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
          }));

          it("Test 1", function (done) {
            ...
            scope.etud = 2.1;
            scope.$digest();
            expect(elm.hasClass("sane")).toBeTruthy();
            expect(elm.hasClass("red_alert")).not.toBeTruthy();
            expect(elm.hasClass("yellow_alert")).toBeTruthy();
            ..
          }
```

It seems like the ng-class function is never called everything works fine if I add the function into the test like...

```
          beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, $rootScope) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
          }));

          it("Test 1", function (done) {
            ...
            scope.etud = 2.1;
            scope.getWarningClass = function(){
              var alertClass = "";
              if(scope.etud <= 2){
                alertClass = "red_alert";
              }
              else if(scope.etud <= 4){
                alertClass = "yellow_alert";
              }
              return alertClass;
            }
            scope.$digest();
            expect(elm.hasClass("sane")).toBeTruthy();
            expect(elm.hasClass("red_alert")).not.toBeTruthy();
            expect(elm.hasClass("yellow_alert")).toBeTruthy();
            ..
          }
```

But now I need the code in 2 places! Any way around this?

Comment: can u add the line where you compile your directive in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple issues here but the moral is use the tag instead so I would do something closer to...

```
var element = angular.element('<warning-box />');
view = $compile(element)(scope);
...
```

This will of course throw an exception about how it isn't expecting another GET call. So you will also need to use [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) to serve up the partial. Now everything is working as expected.